# Perform join in spark only on one co-ordinate of pair key?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have 3 RDDs:

- 1st one is of form ((a,b),c).
- 2nd one is of form (b,d).
- 3rd one is of form (a,e).

How can I perform join in scala over these RDDs such that my final output is of the form `((a,b),c,d,e)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
val rdd1: RDD[((A,B),C)]
val rdd2: RDD[(B,D)]
val rdd3: RDD[(A,E)]

val tmp1 = rdd1.map {case((a,b),c) => (a, (b,c))}
val tmp2 = tmp1.join(rdd3).map{case(a, ((b,c), e)) => (b, (a,c,e))}
val res = tmp2.join(rdd2).map{case(b, ((a,c,e), d)) => ((a,b), c,d,e)}
```

Comment: what if `rdd2 is (a, e)` and `rdd3 is (b, d)` ? You will have to change the codes, isn't it @lev?

Answer (score 1):

With *current implementations of `join` apis for paired rdds*, its *not possible to use condtions*. And you would need conditions when joining to get the desired result.

But you can use *dataframes/datasets* for the `joins`, where you can *use conditions*. So use *dataframes/datasets* for the `joins`. If you want the result of `join` in dataframes then you can proceed with that. In case you want your results in rdds, then *`.rdd` can be used to convert the *dataframes/datasets* to `RDD[Row]`*

Below is the sample codes of it can be done in *scala*

```
//creating three rdds
val first = sc.parallelize(Seq((("a", "b"), "c")))
val second = sc.parallelize(Seq(("b", "d")))
val third = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", "e")))

//coverting rdds to dataframes
val firstdf = first.toDF("key1", "value1")
val seconddf = second.toDF("key2", "value2")
val thirddf = third.toDF("key3", "value3")

//udf function for the join condition
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def joinCondition = udf((strct: Row, key: String) => strct.toSeq.contains(key))

//joins with conditions
firstdf
  .join(seconddf, joinCondition(firstdf("key1"), seconddf("key2"))) //joining first with second
  .join(thirddf, joinCondition(firstdf("key1"), thirddf("key3")))  //joining first with third
  .drop("key2", "key3")     //dropping unnecessary columns
  .rdd    //converting dataframe to rdd
```

You should have output as

```
[[a,b],c,d,e]
```

Comment: if your join condition is a udf, spark will do a cartesian join, and it will be very inefficient

Comment: yes @lev you are correct. its just a possibility that I gave :)